# mysql Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'S' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

I know there are answers on this question , but I can't understand as their question code is not same with mine. 
I have code here:

```
UPDATE S 
SET city=(SELECT city FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams')
WHERE s_name='Smith';
```

I tried to modify code according to the answers from other question:

```
UPDATE S 
SET city=(SELECT city FROM (SELECT* FROM S) AS temta WHERE s_name='Adams')
WHERE s_name='Smith';
```

Even though the query is successful but I get null value, the value is not updated as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

have you tryed so:

```
UPDATE S 
SET city=(SELECT city FROM (SELECT * FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams') AS temta )
WHERE s_name='Smith';
```

OR

```
UPDATE S 
SET city=(SELECT c FROM (SELECT city as c FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams') AS temta )
WHERE s_name='Smith';
```

NOTE: are you sure that subquery result is only one row?

Comment: i tried yours and I still get null value. It seems mysql find the exact place to replace the value, but every time it replace with null, rather than the value of adams

Comment: @June what do you get from `SELECT c FROM (SELECT city as c FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams') AS temta`

Comment: i get "Athens", which is correct . But it seems "set city=" command can't read Athens. I tried UPDATE S 
SET city=(SELECT c FROM (SELECT city as c FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams') AS temta )
WHERE s_name='Smith'  but I still get null

Comment: @June Run subquerie to see what they return: first `SELECT city as c FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams'`; then `SELECT c FROM (SELECT city as c FROM S WHERE s_name='Adams') AS temta`; finally `SELECT city FROM S WHERE  s_name='Adams'`